# tf.keras plot_model error: AttributeError: 'ListWrapper' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, plot, model

I have some model that I load in this way:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
model = load_model('model.h5')
```

but I cannot plot the model..I run this function

```
plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

I get this error:

```
File "/home/dmori/miniconda3/envs/remoteEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/vis_utils.py", line 143, in model_to_dot
layer_name = layer.name
AttributeError: 'ListWrapper' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I don't know really what to do, some suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to see model's details by using `model.summary()`?

Comment: Yes, the model seems to be loaded in the right way

Comment: I am don't see any issues in your code and it should work. Do you have `model.save` code? It would be good if you can share the same with us, so that we can replicate your issue and try to help you.Thanks!